# ui-sref include parameter in ng-repeat loop

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-routing

I have this table:

```
            <table class="table tenant-table text-center">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="text-center">
                            <i class="fa fa-per"></i> Date
                        </th>
                        <th class="text-center">
                            <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> Result
                        </th>
                        <th> </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="(k, v) in loanapps track by $index">
                        <td data-th="Date">{{v.ApplicationDate | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'}}</td>
                        <td data-th="Result">
                          <a ng-if="v.LoanStatus == 'Approved'" ui-sref="approved({loanid: {{v.ApplicationId}}})" class="btn dark btn-sm btn-outline sbold uppercase">
                            <i class="fa fa-share"></i> View
                          </a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                </tbody>
            </table>
```

I'm trying to include a parameter, the application id for the approved redirect but I'm not able to include that value in the url. Is the ui-sref approach I'm taking correct or I need to do some tweak?

Comment: Should be `ui-sref="approved({loanid: v.ApplicationId})" `

Comment: @tanmay I'm getting null for loanid once I'm in the other controller https://i.gyazo.com/de4c2781fb8d750c9905cd6885012a43.png

Comment: could be a problem with the state too.. can you share stateProvider code?

Answer (score 1):

Just had the same issue.  Hopefully I figure out a better way to do it, but for now this will work:

```
approved({loanid: '{{v.ApplicationId}}'})
```